# Error value of input of (change) event in nested *ngFor loop angular

Tags: html, angular

I have a nested `*ngFor` loop on a table:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let dept of salesTarget; let i = index">
      <td>{{dept.dept}}</td>
      <td *ngFor="let month of monthList; let j = index">
        <div class="ui input">
          <input type="number" placeholder="0" [value]="salesTarget[i].target[j]"
                                    (change)="updateValue(i, j, $event)">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

and it looks like this on UI:

[image]

**The problem is when input value on specific department on specific month the whole month value changes**

**(eg. if I input value [3] department 2 on Feb, the whole Feb column changes)**

[image]

I added stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6fw4bu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made few changes to your function

```
    for (let x = 0; x < this.deptList.length; x++) {
      let target = {
        dept: this.deptList[x],
        target: Array(12).fill(0)
      };
      this.salesTarget.push(target);
    }
  }
```

you can also check the same in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sb6o3t?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

It is working fine.

Actually you were referring to the same array for the target, and that's why the value of each array was changing.

Comment: It made sense now. A while ago, it was creating another array. Thank you for the adjustments

Answer (score 1):

Because you have the same variable in each `salesTarget` it's update each element.

You need to generate an array with unique elements:

```
  addDefaultSalesTarget() {
    for (let x = 0; x < this.deptList.length; x++) {
      let target = {
        dept: this.deptList[x],
        target: {... this.defaultTarget}
      };
      this.salesTarget.push({...target});
    }
  }

  updateValue(i:number,j: number, e){
    if(e?.target?.value){
      this.salesTarget[i].target[j] = e?.target?.value
    }
    console.log( this.salesTarget)
}
```

[An updated example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-prfhcb?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I'm new to angular.  `...` is new to me. I'll take this answer too. Thank you. I'll research more about.